# sqlalchemy syntax for using mysql constants

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, literals, func

So i am trying to call the mysql function **TIMEDATEDIFF** with the **SECOND** constant as the first parameter like so

```
    query = session.query(func.TIME(Log.IncidentDetection).label('detection'), func.TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,Log.IncidentDetection, Log.IncidentClear).label("duration")).all()
    print(query)
```

I have tried it as a string and I get a mysql/mariadb error:

```
query = session.query(func.TIME(Log.IncidentDetection).label('detection'), func.TIMESTAMPDIFF("SECOND",Log.IncidentDetection, Log.IncidentClear).label("duration")).all()
print(query)
```

**Gives me this**

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''SECOND', log.`IncidentDetection`, log.`IncidentClear`) AS duration 
FROM log' at line 1 [SQL: 'SELECT TIME(log.`IncidentDetection`) AS detection, TIMESTAMPDIFF(%(TIMESTAMPDIFF_1)s, log.`IncidentDetection`, log.`IncidentClear`) AS duration \nFROM log'] [parameters: {'TIMESTAMPDIFF_1': 'SECOND'}]
```

I am sure it is something simple, some sort of escape sequence or import that I am missing. I have looked through the sqlalchemy documentation to no avail.

Comment: It sounds like you tried to pass in a string in place of a unit.

Comment: Both the first and second example raise an error, the first raises and error because SECOND isn't defined in python, the second fails because "SECOND" isn't a valid parameter for TIMESTAMPDIFF function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get sqlalchemy to parse the string exactly into the query I used the `_literal_as_text()` function

**Working solution**

---

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func, _literal_as_text
# ...
query = session.query(func.TIME(Log.IncidentDetection).label('detection'), func.TIMESTAMPDIFF(_literal_as_text("SECOND"),Log.IncidentDetection, Log.IncidentClear).label("duration")).all()
print(query)
```